# crash when using upper_bound in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have following program which crashed at upper bound call. I am not getting why there is a crash. Any reason why I am having a crash. Thanks for your help and time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum quality { good = 0, bad, uncertain };

struct sValue {
   int time;
   int value;
   int qual;
};

struct CompareLowerBoundValueAndTime { 
    bool operator()( const sValue& v, int time ) const {
        return v.time < time;
    } 

    bool operator()( const sValue& v1, const sValue& v2 ) const { 
        return v1.time < v2.time; 
    }

    bool operator()( int time1, int time2 ) const { 
        return time1 < time2; 
    }   

    bool operator()( int time, const sValue& v ) const  { 
        return time < v.time;    
    } 
}; 

struct CompareUpperBoundValueAndTime { 
    bool operator()( const sValue& v, int time ) const {
        return v.time > time;
    } 

    bool operator()( const sValue& v1, const sValue& v2 ) const { 
        return v1.time > v2.time; 
    }

    bool operator()( int time1, int time2 ) const { 
        return time1 > time2; 
    }   

    bool operator()( int time, const sValue& v ) const  { 
        return time > v.time;    
    } 
}; 

class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass() {
        InsertValues();
    }

       void InsertValues();

       int GetLocationForTime(int time);

       void PrintValueContainer();

private:

    vector<sValue> valueContainer;
};

void MyClass::InsertValues() {
    for(int num = 0; num < 5; num++) {
        sValue temp;
        temp.time = num;
        temp.value = num+1;
        temp.qual = num % 2;
        valueContainer.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void MyClass::PrintValueContainer()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < valueContainer.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i << ". " << valueContainer[i].time << std::endl;
    }
}




int MyClass::GetLocationForTime(int time)
{
    std::vector< sValue >::iterator lower, upper;
    lower =  std::lower_bound(valueContainer.begin(), valueContainer.end(), time, CompareLowerBoundValueAndTime() );

    upper =  std::upper_bound(valueContainer.begin(), valueContainer.end(), time, CompareUpperBoundValueAndTime() ); // Crashing here.

    std::cout << "Lower bound: " << lower - valueContainer.begin() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Upper bound: " << upper - valueContainer.begin() << std::endl;

   return lower - valueContainer.begin();
}



int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    a.PrintValueContainer();
    std::cout << "Location received for 2: "  << a.GetLocationForTime(2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a complete (though slightly excessive) example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) work on a sorted sequence. The sequence has to be sorted using the same comparing function that you pass to both functions.

When you insert the elements in `InsertValues` you insert them in ascending order, so your `CompareLowerBoundValueAndTime` is a correct way to compare them.

But for `upper_bound` you're passing a different compare function. Pass `CompareLowerBoundValueAndTime()` and it should work.

Note that `CompareLowerBoundValueAndTime` is a misleading name. It should be something along the lines of `CompareValueAndTimeAscending`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same comparer for both upper_bound and lower_bound. The difference is in the algorithm, not in the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is giving you the answer. Check your code here: http://ideone.com/x6RE9

This gives you an error saying:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘int MyClass::GetLocationForTime(int)’:
prog.cpp:94: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*upper.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = sValue*, _Container = std::vector<sValue, std::allocator<sValue> >]()’
```

You don't have to dereference `upper` twice, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That is his way of showing what line its crashing on, look at the end, there's 2 stars there as well.

Comment: I think the ** is just highlighting the line where it crashes

Comment: Working code here: http://ideone.com/s2bQm, without the ** (i got that one minute after posting the answer :) )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an assertion error in upper_bound because it is finding that your sequence is not correctly sorted.

You seem to misunderstand what upper_bound does. It is the same as lower_bound except that the item pointed to by the iterator will be strictly greater than the search value, not greater-or-equal. IF there are no such values, it will point to the end of the sequence.

When using a predicate (Pred), it needs to be sorted such that

```
 Pred( iter2, iter1 )
```

will return false whenever iter2 appears later than iter1 in the sequence.

That is not the case with your sequence and predicate combination, therefore you are getting an assertion error.